# Flask Ajax Error 400

Tags: javascript, python, post, flask

i get an error 400 when posting. i'm using flask and sqlalchemy in the backend, and pretty straightforward javascript & jquery
here is the JS:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/create",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          question: question,
          answer1: answer1,
          answer2: answer2,
          answer3: answer3,
          answer4: answer4,
          answer5: answer5,
          answer6: answer6,
          congress: congress,
          session: session,
          date: date,
          lecture: lecture,
          correct: correct
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log("sent");
        }, error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(error);
            }
    });
}
```

and here is the Flask code:

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def cre():
post = QuestionClass(congress=str(request.form['congress']), 
session=str(request.form['session']),
                     date=str(request.form['date']), 
lecture=str(request.form['lecture']),
                     question=str(request.form['question']), 
answer1=str(request.form['answer1']),
                     answer2=str(request.form['answer2']), answer3=str(request.form['answer3']),
                     answer4=str(request.form['answer4']), answer5=str(request.form['answer5']),
                     )

engine = create_engine(sqlite:///DB.db', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sqlsession = Session()
sqlsession.add(post)
sqlsession.commit()
return 1
```

and i can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong...

Comment: Just wondering about  your key : values, for example question: question, I assume the value (after semicolon is a variable), what about the key? If its not a variable, then what you are likely sending is Undefined: question, which flask will not understand. Would you try to make the keys a string? like "question": question and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

I also had a thorough look, but couldn't find anything obvious. I made a small working example, which does exactly what you hope it should be doing. Try adding stuff to the example till you break it.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request, jsonify, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        info = request.form['question']
        print(info)
        return jsonify({'what_you_sent': info})

    return render_template_string('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div></div>
<script>
 $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          question: 'hello?',
          answer1: 'hi',
         },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.what_you_sent);},
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
            alert('such error')}
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
''')


app.run()
```

Just a general tip when debugging 400 errors, just access the form elements one by one instead of directly applying them to a model or whatever, it's easier to spot them like that.

like:

```
print(request.form['question'])
print(request.form['answer1'])
etc...
```

Also clean your browser cache just in case.

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in my comment what the data object represents is a json object and unlike javascript objects, the keys must be strings see [this ref](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp)

Change your data object to (am assuming your values are valid JSON data type (string, number, object, array, boolean or null))

**EDIT** I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192687/trying-to-send-json-using-ajax-sends-query-string-instead/50193458#50193458) and realized the main problem could be that your data was url-encoded by jquery. If you stringify it like below, it should work. Try it on your original code

```
data: JSON.stringify({
          "question": question,
          "answer1": answer1,
          "answer2": answer2,
          "answer3": answer3,
          "answer4": answer4,
          "answer5": answer5,
          "answer6": answer6,
          "congress": congress,
          "session": session,
          "date": date,
          "lecture": lecture,
          "correct": correct
        }),
```

Okay, I will make your flask a bit more complicated, but for a good cause. I will make a wtf form (you can make a normal form but I like the additional features of wtf like validation etc)

```
class QuestionForm(FlaskForm):
    question = StringField('question', [validators.InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid entry")])
    answer1 = StringField('answer1', [validators.InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid entry")])
    answer2 = StringField('answer2', [validators.InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid entry")])
    answer3 = StringField('answer3', [validators.InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid entry")])
    answer4 = StringField('answer4', [validators.InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid entry")])
    answer5 = StringField('answer5', [validators.InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid entry")])
    answer6 = StringField('answer6', [validators.InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid entry")])
    congress = StringField('congress', [validators.InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid entry")])
    session = StringField('session', [validators.InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid entry")])
    date = StringField('date', [validators.InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid entry")])
    lecture = StringField('lecture', [validators.InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid entry")])
    correct = StringField('correct', [validators.InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid entry")])
```

Be sure to make relvant imports if you go with wtf

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, StringField, IntegerField, validators, SelectField, TextAreaField, HiddenField
```

Then I will use werkzeug.datastructures to access the json data (i start with import, import the form as well if it is in a different file `from forms import QuestionForm`), then access all the values of the form. I am returning all the values in a string just to be sure I am receiving them, am sure you will know how to save to your database from there

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict
@app.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
def cre():
    form_data = MultiDict(mapping=request.json)
    form = QuestionForm(form_data)
    if request.is_json:
        question= form.question.data
        answer1= form.answer1.data
        answer2= form.answer2.data
        answer3= form.answer3.data
        answer4= form.answer4.data
        answer5= form.answer5.data
        answer6= form.answer6.data
        congress= form.congress.data
        ssession= form.session.data
        date= form.date.data
        lecture= form.lecture.data
        correct= form.correct.data
    return str(question+' '+answer1+' '+answer2+' '+answer3+' '+answer4+' '+answer5+' '+answer6+' '+congress+' '+ssession+' '+date+' '+lecture+' '+correct)
```

You can add `if form.validate_on_submit():` after the `if request.is_json:` if you wish to validate the data as per the validators you specify on the form

I am able to get a response with all the values I put in my json object. I am sure if you find this example one that can work for you, you will be able to debug from there (I used ssession because on my testing app i already have session defined)

Comment: @Benny have a look at a few additions to the answer and see if it will be useful. I am able to return all the values put in the json object from my view

Comment: Hi @Benny I have added an edit that I think will sort out the problem with your code. Raw json is usually url-encoded by jquery, try the edit I have added with your original code